# Impala access to existing Parquet tables in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudera-cdh, hue, impala, parquet

I have some Parquet tables that were created with SparkSQL stored in S3. I would like to also be able use them from Impala. I also have an instance of Impala running on CDH5 that I can access using Hue.

What do I need to do to query the above data from this Impala instance?

The Impala Parquet documentation seems to be primarily about importing data into Parquet. I already have the data in Parquet and I just want to point Impala at it. I am new to Impala and Hue, my experience with Parquet is from SparkSQL.

Comment: You usually need to create an external table that points to this file, then you can execute SQL statements on it

Answer (score 2):

Impala has [experimental support](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/impala_s3.html) querying data stored in S3. Here's an example `CREATE TABLE` statement for working with Parquet data stored in S3, taken from the documentation linked in the previous sentence:

```
create table sample_data_s3 (id int, id bigint, val int, zerofill
string, name string, assertion boolean, city string, state string)
stored as parquet location 's3a://impala-demo/sample_data';
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff! This is what I am  after. Is there also a way to get Impala to get the column specifications from the Parquet and not specify them with the create statement? My schema has a a rather large number of columns and it would be nice not to have to type them all in.

Comment: Sure do "CREATE TABLE ... LIKE PARQUET"; cf. http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_create_table.html.